# How to get the correct array dimensions to store all results for my DP memoization for N choose K problem?

Tags: c++, recursion, syntax, memoization

I'm learning data-structures and algorithms, I can solve it recursively and I understand I have to add to a memo table to save repetitions, I'm having trouble doing it, some input would be very helpful. If you can also implement the set/ map solution, that would be great too, but I'm primarily looking for array solution for future reference. I think it might be because while passing the array, it's not passed by reference, because c++ doesn't do that, would a vector be a better choice? I tried, but wasn't able to make it work also. And array solution in Java which does pass arrays by reference is also not working, so I'm doing something wrong.

Code:

```
long long int combinMemo(int n, int k, int memo[])  {
    if (k == 0) return 1;
    if (n == k) return 1;
    if(n < k || (n <= 0)) return 0;
    if(memo[k] == 0) {
        return memo[k] = (combinMemo(n - 1, k - 1, memo)) + combinMemo(n - 1, k, memo);          //+ combinMemo(n - 1, k, memo));
    } else {
        return memo[k];
    }
}

long long int combinMemoWrap(int n, int k) {
    int memo[k + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
            memo[i] = 0;
    }
    return combinMemo(n, k, memo);
}
```

Comment: Your cache is an array with `k+1` slots. But, you're using the same `k` slot for all values of `n`. So the lookup is only accurate for one value of `n`

If you want the memoized lookup to be accurate for all values of `n` and `k`, you need `n*k` slots. The index will be something like `n*k+k` so every combination of `n` and `k` get a unique slot.

Comment: Some mistakes in that comment, I got a little mixed up because everything is named 'n' and 'k'. You need `(nMax+1)*(kMax+1)` slots, where `nMax` and `kMax` are the values of `n` & `k` passed to the top level wrapper function. You need to pass the number of rows (`kMax+1`) to your recursive function, and compute the index of your array with `n*(kMax+1) + k`.

Comment: It does work now, can you elaborate how you figured that out? I'm not able to understand even after reading your answer, and why did I have to pass kmax (and it should put kmax not kmax + 1, that one is just so we can put kmax into the array) in the function as an extra parameter and is this a valid c++ code? I know it will work in Java.

Comment: It does work in c++ so I guess it passes a copy of current array not empty array, which makes complete sense. Moving from Java to c++ can be weird.

Comment: On drawing the recursion tree, I'm noticing kmax + 1 is the maximum level deep the tree ever goes, is that why you chose kmax + 1? The code still gives the correct answer with kmax though?

Comment: The reason for all this is, the answer can be different from every value of n and k. I know that's not always true, but it's an easy assumption to get a upper bound. To have a place to memoize all those values, you need the total number of `n` values, times the number of `k`. Since they can be zero, that's `(n+1)*(k*1)`.

Comment: The reason for the `n * (kMax+1) + k` is because to find a unique space for each `n` and `k`, I'm pretending it's a 2D array, with `n` being one dimension and `k` being the other. This website explains how to treat a 1D array like a 2D array: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/memory-layout-of-multi-dimensional-arrays/

Comment: It makes sense now, thank you for your answers!